GH-Action green (success) but doesn't push changes
I have set up a dummy GitHub action which adds (stage) from a folder called data all its content.
   - name: Stage and commit data changes
      run: |
        git add data/ --verbose
        git commit -m "Automated commit of data files"|| echo "No changes to commit"
        git push origin main || echo "No changes to commit"

The sequence is successful, action workflow turns green.
However, when I navigate to that folder, the file is not there (wasn't staged nor pushed). It does exist in my local directory.

It is not in .gitignore and I enabled writing using action. I did not create nor included any secrets for this repo.

[v] Read and write permissions
Workflows have read and write permissions in the repository for all scopes.

Would really like to get some help, why it seems to run but doesn't capture it (add commit push)

which changes you trying to push?

Adding the content of the folder data (in my directory there are three files, two of them should be just updated and one added from scratch)

in your workflow yaml there is no change to any file, you checkout the repo and then add & commit, where is the change?

In my local folder, there is a file called test.txt which is not staged. I want the workflow to stage it (a greedy statement on all content from data, hence data/*), and push to my remote. As I'm writing this I might have done something extremely dumb, because the wf has no way to access to that file right? I must stage it first?

your wf run on:  runs-on: windows-latest which is an hosted agent, where is the changed file? in your local machine?

Hey Shayki, thanks. I managed to solve this issue. I couldn't run it using ubuntu (due to a necessary linux-specific package that was not installed) so i switched to run on windows and now it works. I also modified my add statement to stage all new files (for my RADEME). Thanks! It was a long learning process :)

I switched from Ubuntu to Windows, since I had an error related to a package i needed specifically for Linux (which I obviously cant install, as it runs remotely). It now works on a remote window machine, and I'm quite pleased.
Problem had to do specifically with the cli package (R language)
  push-data:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write  
.
.
.
 - name: Stage and commit data changes
      run: |
        git add . --verbose
        git commit -m "Re-ran scrape at $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" || echo "No changes to commit"
        git push origin main || echo "No changes to commit"

This now works!
